# Cannot create database connection

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I will try to explain the current situation in the best possible way.

Well, I got a VM with SQL Developer already installed but could not run properly. After some research, I solve the problem related with environment variables.

Currently, I need to create a database connection but unsuccessfully. I do not know what are the credentials that I have to use it. I can log in on `sqlplus as sysdba`.

I already did the `select * from all_users` but I'm still stuck on this. Is there anyway to discover the right credentials to create the connection?

Comment: Do you have root access ?

Comment: have you created a user, assigned a password and tested a connection in SQL Developer?

Comment: Have you followed a given tutorial? have you created tnsnames.ora, and is it configured in SQL Developer?

Comment: @kevinsky Do I need to login with username system right? I do not have that password.

Comment: @J.Chomel Yes, the tnsnames.ora is created. How can I check if it is configured in SQL Developer? Do you want a copy of my tnsnames.ora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Vm, when logged in as sysdba

```
CREATE USER WIZ IDENTIFIED BY "YourComplexPassword"
  default tablespace USERS
  temporary tablespace TEMP
  profile DEFAULT;

GRANT Connect TO WIZ;
--might need this too, depends on version
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO WIZ;
```

This gives you a basic user to test connectivity. Then, from SQL Developer, create a new connection to the database using the Service name, host, port 1521 and the user and password you created.  Select "Test". If successful save the connection and you are good to go.

You must verify that the name of the database matches the information you enter into the SQL developer connection dialogue.  If you are using XE the database name will be XE.  Other versions let you customize the name of the database. This information will be in your tnsnames.ora listed as SID or SERVICE_NAME

Comment: Ok the user is created.

Now, when I want to create a new database connection I put:
- username: wiz
- password: "password"
SID: orcl

And it shows: ORA: 01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Comment: I got some prints taken by me at this moment.

1st http://imgur.com/GvOXdtI
2nd http://imgur.com/9QxRMNP

On the second print, I changed the connection type to TNS and runs perfectly.

There is any problem with this connection type? I can use this in a regular way?

Comment: I got the point. I change the service name to SIEBEL DB and works perfectly. Thanks.